# Interval of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $I$ be a non empty interval of rational numbers with rational endpoints, i.e, I can be, open, closed, semi-open, for example:, let $a,b\in\mathbb {Q}$, $a\leq b$ and $[a,b]_{\mathbb{Q}}:=\{x\in\mathbb{Q},a\leq x\leq b\}$, the same with $<a,b>_{\mathbb{Q}}$, $<a,b]_{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $[a,b>_{\mathbb{Q}}$.

(1) Show that I has rational extremes, iff, it has supremum and infimum.

(2) Show that there is a bounded interval of rational numbers such that it is not of the 4 formats above mentioned.

1. $(\Longrightarrow)$ each of the endpoints is the infimum and supremum respectively. $(\Longleftarrow)$ I have a problem here because I can not assure that the supremum and infimum are rational numbers.

**Edited**
2) I do not know how to begin. Let $I$ a bounded interval of rational numbers, so there is $b=\sup (I)$ and $a=\inf(I)$, then

$a\leq x\leq b$, for all $x\in I$, then $I\subset [a,b]$, is that enough? What else can I do?

Comment: What about the rationals between $0$ and $\sqrt2$?

Comment: "I do not know how to begin." Begin with the definitions.

Comment: I edited and added. I get stuck on that, thank you

Comment: I got it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $I$ has rational endpoints. Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ be the endpoints of $I$, where $a \leq b$. Since $I$ is bounded, it follows that $I$ has a supremum and infimum. The supremum and infimum are defined as the least upper bound and greatest lower bound of $I$, respectively. Since $I$ consists of rational numbers and is bounded above and below, the supremum and infimum must also be rational.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Now, assume $I$ has a supremum $s$ and infimum $i$, both of which are rational numbers. We need to show that the endpoints of $I$ are rational.

Case 1: If $s$ and $i$ are both in $I$, then they are the endpoints of $I$, and therefore, they are rational.

Case 2: If $s$ and $i$ lie strictly inside $I$, then $I$ must be of the form $(a, b)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ since $s$ and $i$ are not included in $I$. Since $I$ only contains rational numbers, $s$ and $i$ must be rational.

---

(2) To show that there is a bounded interval of rational numbers that is not in any of the four mentioned formats:

Consider the interval $I = (0, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, where $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number. This interval consists of all rational numbers between 0 and $\sqrt{2}$, excluding $\sqrt{2}$ itself.

$I$ is a bounded interval of rational numbers. However, it does not fall into any of the four formats mentioned:

It is not of the form $[a, b]_{\mathbb{Q}}$ as it does not include its upper endpoint.
It is not of the form $<a, b>_{\mathbb{Q}}$ as it does not include its lower endpoint.
It is not of the form $<a, b]_{\mathbb{Q}}$ as it does not include its lower endpoint.
It is not of the form $[a, b>_{\mathbb{Q}}$ as it does not include its upper endpoint.
Therefore, $I$ serves as an example of a bounded interval of rational numbers that does not fit into any of the mentioned formats.

To demonstrate that a bounded interval of rational numbers can exist without fitting into the four formats mentioned, you can indeed consider the interval $I = (0, \sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. As explained above, this interval consists of all rational numbers between 0 and $\sqrt{2}$ (excluding $\sqrt{2}$ itself).